# Assigning output labels from neural network in python

Tags: python, arrays, neural-network

I have a trained network `model` and I am passing the first 10 images from my testing dataset, in which I am obtaining the estimated output labels, as shown here.

```
model(BIWI_imgs_all[0:10])

<tf.Tensor: id=2584, shape=(10, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.10563646, -0.02891611, -0.40907562],
       [-0.106397  , -0.03694702,  0.34012434],
       [-0.10431363, -0.0306944 , -0.49813306],
       [-0.10416464, -0.02984314, -0.23513329],
       [-0.10422087, -0.03500057,  0.33305332],
       [-0.10443354, -0.03409709, -0.161203  ],
       [-0.07168856, -0.02205666,  0.45544097],
       [-0.11022589, -0.0421547 ,  1.4162855 ],
       [-0.10356671, -0.03270946, -0.17791806],
       [-0.09993703, -0.04214598,  1.2923461 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

I was then attempting to assign each column of my output to [pitch, yaw, roll] as shown:

```
pitch, yaw, roll = model(BIWI_imgs_all[0:10])
```

However I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Is there a way I can assign my output labels as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with:

```py
pitch, yay, roll = tf.unstack(model(BIWI_imgs_all[0:10]), axis=1)
```

Take a look at the documentation to grasp the concept and what it does exactly.